# Automatically shutdown Google Dataproc cluster after all jobs are completed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

How can I programmatically shutdown a Google Dataproc cluster automatically after all jobs have completed?

Dataproc [provides](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/resources/faq) creation, monitoring and management. But it seems I cannot find out how to delete the cluster.

Answer (score 7):

The `gcloud dataproc` CLI interface offers the `max-idle` option.
This automatically kills the Dataproc cluster after an x amount of inactivity (i.e. no running jobs). It can be used as follows:

```sh
gcloud dataproc clusters create test-cluster \
    --project my-test-project \
    --zone europe-west1-b \
    --master-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
    --master-boot-disk-size 100 \
    --num-workers 2 \
    --worker-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
    --worker-boot-disk-size 100 \
    --max-idle 1h
```

Comment: This feature already GA and available in `gcloud dataproc ...` (without `beta`) command.

Comment: Hi Martijn - thanks for your answer, this command will temporarily stop the cluster or will delete it permanently?

Comment: It would kill the entire cluster after the max-idle timeout has been reached.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language. Personally, I use Python (pyspark) and the code provided here worked fine for me:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/dataproc/submit_job_to_cluster.py

You may need to adapt the code to your purpose and follow the prerequisite steps specified in the README file (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/dataproc), like enabling the API and installing the packages in `requirements.txt` .

Basically, using the function `wait_for_job` you wait until the job has finished, and with `delete_cluster` , as the name says, the cluster that you have previously created get deleted.
I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this goal you have three options:

1. Set `--max-idle` property during cluster creation (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54239034/3227693).
2. Use [Dataproc Workflow Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/overview) to manage cluster lifecycle. It can automatically create cluster to execute jobs on and delete cluster after all jobs are finished.
3. Use full-blown orchestration solution as [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/) to manage your clusters and jobs lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of programmable ways to auto shut down the cluster:

1. Call the [REST api](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters/delete) directly
2. [Use the `gcloud` CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/delete)

Either of these could be used (called) after your job(s) finish executing.

See more here:
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/manage-cluster#delete_a_cluster

Comment: I want to completely automate this task. So here how will we get notified when job finish the execution? Once we get job completion callback/notification, REST api could be used to delete the cluster.

Comment: Again, use the REST api. Specically, the `GET` on the job resource and wrap it in a polling loop - https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs/get. So, submit > monitor > shutdown

Comment: Ok. So the external script has to poll the job status and then based on the status,fire different actions on the cluster. Any tools/third-party software which manage the DataProc cluster with auto shutdown and scaling capabilities? Because same problem exists with auto-scaling also. DataFlow handles auto-scaling by itself.

Comment: I don't know of any 3rd party tool. You'd need to hand-roll something yourself.

Comment: Same way could we monitor the cluster health and scale up/down using REST apis?

Comment: Yes, use the API to change num workers - https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters/patch

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Scala code:

- create cluster
- run all job
- when jobs terminated Delete cluster

To do that you can work with Scala Future.

If you have many jobs you can run them in parallel:

```scala
val gcpJarBucket = "gs://test_dataproc/dataproc/Dataproc.jar"
val jobs = Seq("package.class1", "package.class2")
val projectName: String = "automat-dataproc"
val clusterName: String = "your-cluster-name"

val timeout = 180 minute

// Working directory
implicit val wd = pwd

val future = Future {
  println("Creating the spark cluster...")
  % gcloud ("dataproc", "clusters", "create", clusterName, "--subnet", "default", "--zone", "europe-west1-b", "--master-machine-type", "n1-standard-4", "--master-boot-disk-size", "50", "--num-workers", "3", "--worker-machine-type", "n1-standard-4", "--worker-boot-disk-size", "50", "--project", projectName)
  println("Creating the spark cluster...DONE")
}.flatMap { _ =>
  {
    Future.sequence {
      jobs.map { jobClass =>
        Future {
          println(s"Launching the spark job from the class $jobClass...")
          % gcloud ("dataproc", "jobs", "submit", "spark", s"--cluster=$clusterName", s"--class=$jobClass", "--region=global", s"--jars=$gcpJarBucket")
          println(s"Launching the spark job from the class $jobClass...DONE")
        }
      }
    }

  }
}

Try { Await.ready(future, timeout) }.recover { case exp => println(exp) }
% bash ("-c", s"printf 'Y\n' | gcloud dataproc clusters delete $clusterName")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete cluster when spark application finish. here are some examples:

```
private SparkApplication(String[] args) throws
                                        org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException,
                                        IOException,
                                        InterruptedException {

    // Your spark code here

    if (profile != null && profile.equals("gcp")) {
        DataProcUtil.deleteCluster(clusterName);
    }
}
```

And here is how you delete your cluster by java

```
 public static void deleteCluster(String clusterName) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    logger.info("Try to delete cluster: {}....", clusterName);

    Process process = new ProcessBuilder("gcloud",
                                         "dataproc",
                                         "clusters",
                                         "delete",
                                         clusterName,
                                         "--async",
                                         "--quiet").start();

    int errCode = process.waitFor();
    boolean hasError = (errCode == 0 ? false : true);
    logger.info("Command executed, any errors? {}", hasError);
    String output;
    if (hasError) {
        output = output(process.getErrorStream());
    }
    else {
        output = output(process.getInputStream());
    }

    logger.info("Output: {}", output);

}

private static String output(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line)
              .append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        }
    }
    return sb.toString();

}
```